# Por que no puedo enviar el valor del qlineedit

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, Qt
import threading
from Inicio import *

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/N_Proyect/Interfaces/Login.ui",self)



        self.b_login.clicked.connect(lambda:Dato())

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)

        self.closed.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.mostrar_hora)
        t.start()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.mostrar_hora)
        self.timer.start()

    def mostrar_hora(self):
        self.hora.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss AP"))

class Dato:
    def __init__(self):
        self.principal = Principal()
        self.inicio = Inicio()
        self.inicio.show()
        self.inicio.user.setText('k')
        print(self.principal.l_usuario.text())

app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

estoy tratando de mandar el valor del qline edit del modulo login al label que se encuentra en el modulo inicio,
todo esto lo hago en la clase dato pero no invia el valor.

Comment: ¿Qué importas de `Inicio`? El uso de `*` hace difícil averiguarlo. Por otro lado, ¿dónde estás intentando enviar el valor de `qlineedit`? No veo nada parecido en el código que has pegado.